# Modify numbers inside list with lambda and map functions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, map-function

for homework I need to create a function that receives 2 list of numbers and every time a number from the first list matches with one of the second one I have to add `10` to the number in the first list. Here's what I've tried.

```
def modifyEspecials(mylist,especials):
  return list(map(lambda n: str(int(n)+10) if map(lambda x: True if n==x else False,especials)== True else n,mylist))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  especials=[*range(39,48),*range(58,63),*range(91,97)]
  mylist= ['72', '45', '41', '56', '46', '56', '49', '45', '48', '41', '39', '46', '71', '52', '46', '56', '52', '46', '42']
  modifiedList= modifyEspecials(mylist,especials)
  print(modifiedList)
```

This returns the same list.

Note: I can't create variables inside `modifyEspecials()` in this homework and I'm only allowed to import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase and functools or for/while loops

Comment: For starters `mylist` is a list of strings, not numbers.

Comment: I think you're making it overcomplicated. Look into list comprehensions instead of using map and lambdas

Comment: are you required to use lambda/map?

Comment: Yes, I'm required to make it overcomplicated

Comment: Mission accomplished then - `mylist` is all strings, it's not the same length as `especials`, it's unclear if you need to add 10 when two values in matching positions are the same, or only if a value from the first is in the second list at all. Your function body is very complicated, but does the same as `return list(map(lambda n: str(int(n)+10) if False else n, mylist))`, so it's the same as `return list(map(lambda n: n, mylist))` or really `return list(mylist)` - and that's what it does.

Comment: so just to clarify, you're not allowed to use list comprehension? @RaCo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have to use this overcomplicated methods to do so, there is 2 mistakes you do:

1. In the second `map` you compare string of int with ints
2. The second `map` returns an iterator of size `especials`

In order to overcome the first issue just transform to int, for the second issue just sum all elements after transforming to list, if there is at least 1 `True` than you should add `10`

See the following fix:

```
def modifyEspecials(mylist,especials):
  return list(map(lambda n: str(int(n)+10) if sum(list(map(lambda x: True if int(n)==x else False, especials))) > 0 else n, mylist))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  especials=[*range(39,48),*range(58,63),*range(91,97)]
  mylist= ['72', '45', '41', '56', '46', '56', '49', '45', '48', '41', '39', '46', '71', '52', '46', '56', '52', '46', '42']
  modifiedList= modifyEspecials(mylist,especials)
  print(modifiedList)
```

*Note* Although `map` and `lambda` are powerful, its not always advisable to use them where there is no need to.